# handle 'URL prompts save file' python

Tags: python, json, request, wget, savefiledialog

Please don't say selenium.
it should be an easy step. thank you!

```
    #usr/bin/python 3.6 on win10x64

    from datetime import datetime
    import json
    import requests

    current_time = datetime.datetime.now(datetime.timezone.utc)
    url = 'https://api.nicehash.com/livePubJSON?l=0&a=07callback=superagentCallback'+str(round(int(current_time.timestamp()), 2)).replace('.','')
    js_file = requests.get(url).json() #this is not correct, and also it will always send the 'livePubJSON.js' file
    with open(r'C\Users\[myusername]\Downloads\livePubJson.js') as json_data: # being API file.js i would like to be replaced
        d = json.load(json_data)
        print(d)
```

please help me to make this a loop because it's an API

to save time:
response is 200 but I think i need headers HTTP error 403 so here are some copy paste i grabbed from youtube:
headers['User-Agent'] = 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i868) AppleWebKit/537.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/24.0.1312.27 Safari/537.17'

Next is the livePubJSON.js output(from browser UI) and have to read parse it as JSON:
superagentCallback1518811920564( {"eu":{"valid":true,"updated":1518811927,
"totalSpeed":6.6999,"orders":[[720747,1,1,2.3261,0.01,29,0.0105],...

Comment: Selenium is the answer here. Adding the tag.

Comment: i just tried something it didn't work and took too long, also haven't found anything in help(webdriver.*) about savefiledialog, i guess you think i should treat it as an alert as in: Alert(webdriver.chrome).accept()

Comment: Can you show us a snapshot of what exactly you mean by `prompt alert save js file`?

Comment: post was edited. please review. (it's getting too complicated)